# How to do sum of elements for multiple list in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to combine two item list by sum of items group by it's count. object definition:`Item (name:String, count:Long}`

```
var list1 : MutableList<Item> = //From API 1 call
var list2 : MutableList<Item>= //From API 2 call
```

Example:

```
Item 1: [{"pen",2}, {"pencil", 3}]
Item 2: [{"pen",6}, {"chair", 2}]
```

Output like:

```
Final list: [{"pen",8}, {"pencil", 3},  {"chair", 2}]
```

How do I achieve in kotlin using any collection inbuilt function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to use [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) and [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

```
val itemsCount = (list1 + list2)          // concat lists
    .groupBy { it.name }                  // group items by name
    .values                               // take list of values
    .map {                                // for each list
        it.reduce {                       // accumulate counts
            acc, item -> Item(item.name, acc.count + item.count)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Pelocho :) What reduce do!!

Comment: As the documentation (lisked in the answer) specifies: *Accumulates value starting with the first element and applying operation from left to right to current accumulator value and each element.*

Answer (score 2):

You can add lists, group and then map values:

```
val l = list1 + list2
val r = l.groupBy { it.name }                   //Map<String, List<Item>>
    .mapValues { it.value.map { it.count }.sum() }    //Map<String, Long>
    .toList()                                   //List<Pair<String, Long>>
    .map { p -> Item(p.first, p.second) }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but I need object not map as specified by Pelocho

Comment: Ok, I simplified it a bit and added `toList()` to get List, not Map

Comment: @amorfis I think he wants a List<Item> not a list of pairs

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Product(val productId: String, val quantity: Double)

val groupedProducts = products
                .groupBy { it.productId }
                .values
                .map {
                    it.reduce {
                        accumulator, product ->
                            product.copy(quantity = accumulator.quantity + product.quantity)
                }
            }
```